# JPA 2.0 insufficient privileges when performing insert from transaction

Tags: java, jpa, insert, persistence, jpa-2.0

After much searching and trials, I am stuck...  I have two classes, one is ExpectedSecurityReturn and the other is ForecastReturnType.  ForecastReturnType is a member of ExpectedSecurityReturn but should not be inserted when persisting data.  I keep getting an "insufficient privileges" but I know that the user does have the delete/insert privileges to the table expected_security_return since I tested with JDBC and JPA delete works fine.  Therefore, I think that it has to do with my classes.

```
@Table(name = "EXPECTED_SECURITY_RETURNS")
@Entity
@IdClass(ExpectedSecurityReturn.ExpectedSecurityReturnPK.class)
public class ExpectedSecurityReturn {

@Id
@Column(name = "REP_SEC_ID")
private Integer repSecId;

@Id
@Column(name = "AS_OF_DATE")
private Date date;

@Id
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "RETURN_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "RETURN_TYPE_ID", insertable=false)
private ForecastReturnType returnType;

@Column(name="CURR_TOUSD_RET")  // local currency to usd 
private Double currencyToUsdReturn;
}
```

The primary key class, which includes ForecastReturnType:

```
    // ------------------------------
// PK
// ------------------------------
public static class ExpectedSecurityReturnPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1325372032981567439L;

    public ExpectedSecurityReturnPK() {
    }

    public ExpectedSecurityReturnPK(final Integer repSecId,
            final Date asOfDate, ForecastReturnType returnType) {
        if (repSecId == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null rep sec id");
        if (asOfDate == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null asOfDate");
        if (returnType == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null returnType");

        this.repSecId = repSecId;
        this.date = new Date(asOfDate.getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        final ExpectedSecurityReturnPK that = (ExpectedSecurityReturnPK) o;

        if (repSecId != that.repSecId)
            return false;
        if (!date.equals(that.date))
            return false;
        if (!returnType.equals(that.returnType))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = repSecId;
        result = 31 * result + date.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + returnType.getForecastTypeId();
        return result;
    }

    private int repSecId;
    private Date date;
    private ForecastReturnType returnType;
}
```

and ForecastReturnType:

```
@Table(name="EXPECTED_SEC_RET_TYPE_DECODE")
@Entity
public class ForecastReturnType {

@Id
@Column(name="RETURN_TYPE_ID")
private int forecastTypeId;

@Column(name="SHORT_NAME")
private String shortName;

@Column(name="LONG_NAME")
private String longName;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="returnType")
Collection<ExpectedSecurityReturn> expectedSecurityReturns;
}
```

Could anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?  I tried many things without success...  I think that the culprit is ExpectedSecurityReturn.returnType since I know that the user does not have privileges.

Basically, I need to insert/persist ExpectedSecurityReturn instances.

Comment: Look in the log for the JPA implementation and tell people what SQL is being invoked, and the details of the exception (and its stack trace)

Comment: Seconded, if you're using PostgreSQL, you can alter postgresql.conf (often in /var/pgsql) and enable logging on the server, look for the logging section, there's normally copious comments to help.  If you're using MySQL, you can add logging in my.cnf (often in /etc) to log all queries, if you're using Oracle, you should see it in V$SQL.  I don't know MSSQL well enough to know if you can log all queries, but I think you can get a history of database locks through SQL Studio.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the sql statement so I think it has to do with the primary key including a foreign key.  Somehow it needs to have sufficient rights to the return type table). The insert SQL is: insert into EXPECTED_SECURITY_RETURNS (CURR_TOUSD_RET, EXCESS_TOSECTOR_RET, EXCESS_TOTREAS_RET, LOCAL_RET, TREASURY_CARRY_RET, TREASURY_RET, AS_OF_DATE, REP_SEC_ID, RETURN_TYPE_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's a couple of things.

I would heavily not recommend even trying to do this.  You can waste away your life figuring out JPA annotations and weird issues like this that never quite seem to work right.  You'll also find that different JPA providers will behave slightly differently when it comes to more complex structures like this, and it goes doubly for inheritance.

You're really much better off creating a unique key on EXPECTED_SECURITY_RETURNS, and just living with it, it will make your Java life much much easier.

If you *have* to do something like this, I'm not surprised that JPA is balking at having a primary key component be another entity object.  Whilst this in of course quite possible in the RDBMS, it's seemingly little things like this that will trip up JPA.

I would also check the query logs that your JPA impl will put out (it's configurable fairly easily in the persistence definition for most JPA providers, certainly Ecpliselink and Hibernate).  I'd be willing to bet it's trying to run an update on EXPECTED_SEC_RET_TYPE_DECODE, and if not, it might be trying to obtain a lock (table, row or other depending on your DBMS).  If the user doesn't have permission to either execute a lock or an update on that table, depending on the exact implementation, the query could fail with a permissions problem.

It is reasonable for JPA to want to hold a lock on that table because there is a chance that during the transaction, the entry that is being referenced in EXPECTED_SEC_RET_TYPE_DECODE may get changed, so it must ensure that it doesn't whilst updating/inserting on the other table.  Last I checked, there is no way to tell JPA that this table is essentially static.  If you're using Hibernate, you might try the @ReadOnly annotation, but in the past, not much I've tried can get around things like this.

If you do find a better solution, feel free to post it so that the rest of us can learn!!

Comment: Thanks for your posts.  I will take a look and figure out what to do next.  I will post again when I have resolved this conflict.  You would think that JPA could work it out since composite PKs are very common place in table design.  I think that you are correct about the issue relating to EXPECTED_SEC_RET_TYPE_DECODE.  That's my thought as well.  I may try to replace the ExpectedSecurityReturn.returnType with an int (since ForecastReturnType's PK is an int) and forget the object itself (ForecastReturnType).

Comment: They are fairly common, I agree.  Link tables are the most common varieties, and JPA does a good job with those with the @JoinTable annotation.  Generally the sacrifice made by adding a new primary key column to what is essentially a join table with metadata isn't large.  The constraint ramifications are small, as both foreign keys (or more) are mapping in foreign key constraints, and you can create a unique index in SQL to simulate primary key behaviour. PostgreSQL uses unique indexes in just this way, so as far as it's concerned, there is no difference as there is an internal row id anyway.

Comment: One problem arises with lazy-loading vs eager loading.  If there are too many tables that have composite primary keys, it becomes very dangerous for an ORM.  To verify integrity, it may sometimes have to fetch a very large amount of table information, particularly if the composite primary key is comprised of foreign keys.  A similar situation arises with one-to-many associations.  When you traverse an object graph in either, the poor ORM literally has no way of knowing your intentions for that data, so can't optimize the fetch process to a reasonable query leaving your network link thrashing.

Comment: I made changes to the exp. return object thinking it would solve the problem such as the ForecastReturnType object is @Transient and added and int returnTypeId thinking it would make things easier and fix the issue.  It did not.  I still get the same "insufficient privileges error".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with PlexQ that derived identities and composite keys are pretty complicated parts of JPA.

However, JPA 2.0 specification contains a good set of examples to illustrate these topics, and these examples mostly work across different JPA implementations.

For your case specification suggests you to put into `@IdClass` a field with name of `@ManyToOne` field and type of `@Id` field of referenced entity:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id long empId;
    String empName;
    ...
}

public class DependentId {
    String name; // matches name of @Id attribute
    long emp; // matches name of @Id attribute and type of Employee PK
}

@Entity
@IdClass(DependentId.class)
public class Dependent {
    @Id String name;
    // id attribute mapped by join column default
    @Id @ManyToOne Employee emp;
    ...
```

}

**See also:**

- [JSR 317: Java<sup>TM</sup> Persistence 2.0](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally figured out that the error was legitimate and I did not indeed have sufficient (ie insert) privileges, only delete!!